# How to insert record with a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have a class `Consignments` in this class I have a relationship to a `Sims` class:

```
class Consignments(Base):
    __tablename__ = "consignments"
    id = Column(
        Integer,
        Sequence('consignments_id', optional=True),
        primary_key=True
    )
    consignment_agents_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Agents.id))    
    consignment_agent = relationship(
        Agents,
        primaryjoin=Agents.id == consignment_agents_id,
        uselist=False,
        backref="consignments"
    )
    consignment_teamleader_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Agents.id))
    consignment_teamlead = relationship(
        Agents,
        primaryjoin=Agents.id == consignment_teamleader_id,
        uselist=False,
        backref="team_consignments"
    )
    consignment_timestamp = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    created_by_agent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Agents.id))
    created_by_agent = relationship(
        Agents,
        primaryjoin=Agents.id == created_by_agent_id,
        uselist=False,
        backref="created_consignments"
    )
    transactions_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Transactions.id))
    transaction = relationship(Transactions, backref="consignments", uselist=False)
    status = Column(Unicode(40), index=True)
    complete_stamp = Column(DateTime, index=True)

    sims = relationship(Sims, secondary=consignment_to_sim, backref="consignments")
```

Notice: `sims` the relationship `consignment_to_sim` this is a table:

```
consignment_to_sim = Table(
    "consignment_to_sim",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("sims_iccid", Unicode(40), ForeignKey("sims.iccid"), primary_key=True, onupdate="cascade"),
    Column(
        "consignments_id",
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("consignments.id"),
        primary_key=True
    )
)
```

Now I am tying to add a consignment like:

```
@task
def do_consignment_task(store):
    s = sqlahelper.get_session()
    consign = store.gen_consignment()
    ca = Agents.by_id(store.consignment_agents_id)
    consign.consignment_agents_id = store.consignment_agents_id
    consign.consignment_teamleader_id = ca.ou[0].lead_agents_id
    consign.consignment_timestamp = func.now()
    consign.created_by_agent_id = store.consignment_agents_id
    consign.complete_stamp = func.now()
    consign.status = "SUCCESS"
    for sim in store.sims:
        consign.sims.append(sim)
    s.add(consign)
transaction.savepoint()
```

`store.sims` is a list of sims.

The above code gives me the following error:

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '1302-37050' for key 'PRIMARY'", None)
```

I have tried suggestions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2310153/2173793) with no luck. I have also viewed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6812910/2173793)

**1 -** What am I doing wrong in my instance?
**2 -** How can I insert into a many-to-many table?
**3 -** Can I use [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert) to insert into a many-to-many?

Just for in case, here is the full [traceback](http://bpaste.net/show/vOsJ4ab5wnJyLH634zek/)

Comment: That's a weird error message. The primary key for a many-to-many table should be composite, which I thought you did, yet it only shows a single value for the duplicate entry?

Comment: That is what is weird to me as well, I cant figure it out... if you look at the traceback, the `37050` is supposed to be the second value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem,
I just added a check in the `for` loop:

```
for sim in store.sims:
    if sim in consign.sims:
        continue
    else:
        consign.sims.append(sim)
s.add(consign)
```

Though there was no duplicate entry in the list, this seems to have solved it.
I hope this could help someone.