# How to update many to many table in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm studying flask, trying to write a simple personal blog. The problem is how to update tags in post.
Models are:

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
  db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
  db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
)

class Post(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(150), index = True)
  post_preview = db.Column(db.String(500), index = True, unique = True)
  post_body = db.Column(db.Text(), index = True, unique = True)
  date = db.Column(db.DateTime(), index = True)
  tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
      backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<Title %r>' % (self.title)


class Tag(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  text = db.Column(db.String(50), index = True)

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.text

  def __init__(self, txt):
    self.text = txt
```

I'm update post with this code from update form:

```
Post.query.filter_by(id = post_id).update({"title":form.title.data, "post_preview":form.post_preview.data, "post_body":form.post_body.data})
```

---

This is my attempt, the code works as it should but I think it is not the best way to achieve it. Is there a better way to update the tags?

```
form_tags=[]
if (form.tags):
    form_tags = form.tags.data.split(',')
for i,t in enumerate(form_tags):
    tmp = t.strip()
    form_tags[i] = tmp

new_tags=[]
old_tags=[]
for t in form_tags:
    obj = Tag.query.filter_by(text=t).first()
    if obj:
        old_tags.append(obj)
    else:
        new_tags.append(t)

for t in old_tags:
    post.tags = old_tags
for t in new_tags:
    post.tags.append(Tag(t))
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: How are you getting object related to `Tag` ? I mean do you have access to `Tag id` in the place where you are updating the `Post`?

Comment: Not sure that understand you right. Ofcourse i can get all the tags from concrete Post by id and then get Tag id.

Comment: @Pradeepb sry, see my answer above

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812910/how-to-use-many-to-many-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @Pradeepb thanks. But i already write some code that do what i need. I updated the original post, maybe you have some advices how to make it not so ugly.

Comment: i am no expert in this but in the link I provided, the OP has done quiet well to resolve it. in the `Tag` model, OP has added `@staticmethod
    def get(dbsession, text):
        obj = dbsession.query(Tag).filter(Tag.text == text).first()
        if not obj:
            obj = Tag(text)
        return obj` . I have modified it for you if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
post.tags = []
db.session.commit()
for tag in form.tags:
    post.tags.append(tag)
```

Comment: Are you saying that this is better solution or asking if OP found a better solution?

Comment: i'm saing this is my way to fix this problem but i'm not sure if there is a better way to do this